# Buzz - disabling SSL verification in POST request

Tags: rest, symfony, http, buzz

How to disable SSL verification in POST request using Buzz php library? Founded here: [Buzz - Scripted HTTP browser](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)

I want to achieve something like using cURL with "-k" flag.

Comment: Show your code, how do you perform a request right now?

Comment: Currently I have error. Here is log: "CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Buzz\Exception\RequestException: "SSL: certificate subject name 'localhost' does not match target host name '172.16.170.44'" at /code/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php line 29 "

Comment: I want to ommit SSL verification. I've used in Buzz client setVerifyPeer(false) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not asking for a problem explanation but for a code you're using.